# How to tell if a window will be listed in the Task Switcher / taskbar?

Tags: c++, windows, taskbar

I'm trying to write a function that takes an `HWND` as an argument and returns `true` if that window will be listed in the Task Switcher, i.e. the window that appears when you press Alt+Tab. I'm not 100% certain, but I think all Windows that appear in the taskbar also appear in the Task Switcher. In the case of a child window, I want it to check this for its root ancestor window.

Right now I'm checking if the root window is visible and its styles / extended styles. Here's some example code:

```
bool VisibleInTaskSwitcher(HWND window) {
    HWND root = GetAncestor(window, GA_ROOT);
    
    if (root == NULL || !IsWindowVisible(root)) {
        return false;
    }
    
    long style = GetWindowLong(root, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    
    if (style & WS_EX_APPWINDOW) {
        return true;
    }

    if (style & WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW || style & WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Is this function correct? Are there any other cases in which a window would not be listed in the task bar that I've missed? (Or perhaps an edge case where it would be even though it fails one of the tests in my function?)

I tested this in Windows 10 and found that windows with the `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP` extended style seem like they also needed to be excluded. Is this the correct thing to do?